# How do I send , pointer to array from JNI C code, to Java code?

Tags: java, c, pointers, java-native-interface

How do I send a pointer to array from JNI C code to a Java code ? For example :

*JNI C Code :*

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"print"," ?? "); // What should be the signature here ?
jvalue a1,*arr;
a1.i = 2002;
a1.f = 12.90;
a1.c = 's';
a1.j = 344554;
a1.b = TRUE;
arr = &a1;
(*env)->CallVoidMethodA(env,obj,mid,arr);
```

*Java Func :*

```
public void print(?????) { // what should be the argument here ?
  // add code here
}
```

How should the java function look like to receive a pointer to an array ?

Comment: @auselen leave this comment under all the questions on SO !(This homework is  a preparatory work for some module I want to write) Next time try to give a better answer,so that you don't get **2 downvotes**..

Comment: Are there any special reasons to why you are using `CallVoidMethodA()` instead of the more easy `CallVoidMethod()`?

Answer (score 1):

First off, two problems with your code:

1. `arr` is not actually an array (it points to a single jvalue), so therefore there's no reason to pass it by pointer instead of just by value.
2. All those `a1.X` assignments are useless, except the last one, because `jvalue` is a *union* of all the possible primitive and reference types.

Next: It's impossible to pass raw C pointers to JNI (well, you can, but you can only get Java to see the pointer as a number and not as an object). You have to create a Java array or buffer object. Arrays are good if you will be creating an array of references, though the memory will have to be copied; buffers are good if you want the C array to share memory with the Java buffer.